# How do I get around the fact that boundary conditions don't apply in the equation's region of validity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, boundary-conditions

> A tight string lies along the positive x-axis when unperturbed. Its displacement from the x-axis is denoted by $y(x, t)$. It is attached to a boundary at $x = 0$. The condition at the boundary is
>   $$y+\alpha \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} =0$$
>   where $\alpha$ is a constant.
>
> Write the displacement as the sum of an incident wave and reflected wave,
>   $$y(x, t) = e^{−ikx−i\omega t} + re^{ikx−i\omega t},\qquad x > 0,$$
>   and compute the reflection coefficient, $r$. Writing $r = |r|e^{i\phi}$, show that $|r| = 1$
>   and find $\phi$.

But since the boundary condition applies at $x=0$ and the equation given is only valid for $x>0$ I can't use that, so what equation should I use?

(If you just apply the condition that the incident and reflected wave are equal at $x=0$, since there is no transmission, you get what I believe is the desired result, but how would one go about this problem with the method it wants)

Comment: It could just be a typo: the equation should apply for x=0. The fact that this problem does not have any other boundary conditions makes me think it is one. Mistakes happen. :)

Comment: I suppose so, but that doesn't make the question particularly easy to answer

Comment: You *can* use the equation at the boundary of the domain of validity. This can be made perfectly rigorous mathematically (which I'm hoping someone will write up more fully) using any one of a number of tools.

Comment: Someone explained on my [re-post over at physics forums](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=749902), though I would like to see a more rigorous argument if anyone is willing